# Best performance method for evaluating presence of substrings within strings in python?

Tags: python, string

I know I can do:

```
word = 'shrimp'
sentence = 'They eat shrimp in Mexico, and even more these days'
word in sentence
```

And so it'd would evaluate `True`.

But what if I have:

```
words = ['a','la','los','shrimp']
```

How can I evaluate whether sentence contains any `words` elements?

**I care for performance as list might be large and I don't want to extend code lines using loops**

Comment: Your first example returns `False` (case-sensitivity). Is that intentional?

Comment: I missed it @OneKitten. Good eye

Comment: Should `'ban'` be counted as appearing in `'fresh bananas'`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
>>> words = ['a','la','los','shrimp']
>>> sentence = 'They eat shrimp in Mexico, and more these days'
>>> [word for word in words if word in sentence]
['a', 'shrimp']
>>> any(word in sentence for word in words)
True
```

---

```
words = ['a','la','los','shrimp']
sentence = 'They eat shrimp in Mexico, and more these days'
a = map(lambda word: word in words if word in sentence else None, words)
print(a.__next__())
True
```

There are many ways to perform this.

Since you asked for Performance, here are the results.

```
In [1]: words = ['a','la','los','shrimp']

In [2]: sentence = 'They eat shrimp in Mexico

In [3]: a = map(lambda word: word in words if word in sentence else None, words)

In [4]: a.__next__()
Out[4]: True

In [5]: %timeit a
10000000 loops, best of 3: 65.3 ns per loop

In [6]: b = any(word in sentence for word in words)

In [7]: %timeit b
10000000 loops, best of 3: 50.1 ns per loop
```

---

```
words = ['a','la','fresh','shrimp','ban']
sentence = 'They fresh bananas in Mexico, and more these days'
a = [word for word in words if word in sentence.split(' ')]
print(a) #['fresh']

b = any(word in sentence.split(' ') for word in words)
print(b) #True
```

Comment: Your answer is mostly a duplicate of mine.

Comment: You just edited your post to include the answer given by @RamchandraApte.

Comment: @machineyearning Well, it might not intentional; maybe he didn't see my answer.

Comment: I assumed op wanted that, so used list comprehension.

Comment: @ajkumar25 No, in the question, `How can I evaluate whether sentence contains any words elements?`.

Comment: Great, what about the comment after my post:

*Should 'ban' be counted as appearing in 'fresh bananas'?*

And of course not, that shouldn't be counted

Comment: @diegoaguilar `filter()` code doesn't count ban in fresh bananas.

Comment: But how can it be applied in your answer?

Comment: So last implementations would be the ones

Answer (score 7):

Could be read as English. But might not be the most performant. First benchmark and then only if needed, use an optimized solution.

```
any(word in sentence for word in words)
```

[any](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#any) returns True if any element is True, otherwise False. `(word in sentence for word in words)` is an iterable, which produces whether each word is in the sentence or not.

Answer (score 1):

```
for word in words:
    if word in sentence:
        #do stuff
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is what i Found.

Testing is done on 100k words:

NB: Generating sets is expensive inside the function if your list is long, BUT if you can pre-process into set before calling the function then, set will win.

Snippet:

```
#!/usr/bin/python

import cProfile
from timeit import Timer
from faker import Faker


def func1(sentence, words):
    return any(word in sentence for word in words)

def func2(sentence, words):
    for word in words:
        if word in sentence:
            return True
    return False

def func3(sentence, words):
    # using set
    sets = set(sentence)
    return bool(set(words).intersection(sets))

def func4(sentence, words):
    # using set
    sets = set(sentence)
    for word in words:
        if word in sets:
            return True
    return False

def func5(sentence, words):
    # using set
    sentence, words = set(sentence), set(words)
    return not words.isdisjoint(sentence)

s = Faker()
sentence = s.sentence(nb_words=100000).split()
words = 'quidem necessitatibus minus id quos in neque omnis molestias'.split()

func = [ func1, func2, func3, func4, func5 ]

for fun in func:
    t = Timer(lambda: fun(sentence, words))
    print fun.__name__, cProfile.run('t.timeit(number=1000)')
```

Output:

**Result: func2 wins**

```
func1          5011 function calls in 0.032 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.032    0.032 <string>:1(<module>)
     1000    0.000    0.000    0.032    0.000 exists.py:42(<lambda>)
     1000    0.001    0.000    0.032    0.000 exists.py:8(func1)
     2000    0.030    0.000    0.030    0.000 exists.py:9(<genexpr>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 timeit.py:143(setup)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.032    0.032 timeit.py:178(timeit)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.032    0.032 timeit.py:96(inner)
     1000    0.000    0.000    0.030    0.000 {any}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.disable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.enable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.isenabled}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {globals}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.time}


None
func2          2011 function calls in 0.031 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.031    0.031 <string>:1(<module>)
     1000    0.031    0.000    0.031    0.000 exists.py:11(func2)
     1000    0.000    0.000    0.031    0.000 exists.py:42(<lambda>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 timeit.py:143(setup)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.031    0.031 timeit.py:178(timeit)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.031    0.031 timeit.py:96(inner)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.disable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.enable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.isenabled}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {globals}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.time}


None
func3          3011 function calls in 7.079 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    7.079    7.079 <string>:1(<module>)
     1000    7.069    0.007    7.073    0.007 exists.py:17(func3)
     1000    0.004    0.000    7.077    0.007 exists.py:42(<lambda>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 timeit.py:143(setup)
        1    0.000    0.000    7.079    7.079 timeit.py:178(timeit)
        1    0.002    0.002    7.079    7.079 timeit.py:96(inner)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.disable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.enable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.isenabled}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {globals}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
     1000    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 {method 'intersection' of 'set' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.time}


None
func4          2011 function calls in 7.022 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    7.022    7.022 <string>:1(<module>)
     1000    7.014    0.007    7.014    0.007 exists.py:22(func4)
     1000    0.006    0.000    7.020    0.007 exists.py:42(<lambda>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 timeit.py:143(setup)
        1    0.000    0.000    7.022    7.022 timeit.py:178(timeit)
        1    0.002    0.002    7.022    7.022 timeit.py:96(inner)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.disable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.enable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.isenabled}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {globals}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.time}


None
func5          3011 function calls in 7.142 seconds

   Ordered by: standard name

   ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.000    0.000    7.142    7.142 <string>:1(<module>)
     1000    7.133    0.007    7.134    0.007 exists.py:30(func5)
     1000    0.006    0.000    7.140    0.007 exists.py:42(<lambda>)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 timeit.py:143(setup)
        1    0.000    0.000    7.142    7.142 timeit.py:178(timeit)
        1    0.002    0.002    7.142    7.142 timeit.py:96(inner)
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.disable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.enable}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {gc.isenabled}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {globals}
        1    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {method 'disable' of '_lsprof.Profiler' objects}
     1000    0.002    0.000    0.002    0.000 {method 'isdisjoint' of 'set' objects}
        2    0.000    0.000    0.000    0.000 {time.time}


None
```

Comment: What about *Should 'ban' be counted as appearing in 'fresh bananas'?* And answer is **no**, how to accomplish it?

Comment: if you wanna check for substring match then try using string.find('pattern') or string.index('pattern')